# identify letter/number combinations using regex and storing in dictionary

Tags: regex, python-3.x, string, pandas, dictionary

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['This 1-A16-19 person is BL-17-1111 and other',
                          'dont Z-1-12 do here but NOT 12-24-1981',
                          'numbers: 1A-256-29Q88 ok'], 
                  'IDs': ['A11','B22','C33'],
                  })
```

Using the `dataframe` above I want to do the following 1) Use `regex` to identify all digit + number combination e.g `1-A16-19` 2) Store in dictionary

Ideally I would like the following output (note that `12-24-1981` intentionally was not picked up by the regex since it doesn't have a letter in it e.g. `1A-24-1981`)

```
{1: 1-A16-19, 2:BL-17-1111, 3: Z-1-12, 4: 1A-256-29Q88}
```

Can anybody help me do this?

Comment: Use `dataframe.extractall(regex)`. I can't see a pattern from the strings you want. Go to [Regex 101](https://regex101.com) to play with the pattern

Comment: I guess the pattern would be any combination of letters and digits seperated by `-`

Comment: How about “but not 12-24-1981”?

Comment: `12-24-1981` should not be picked up because it does not have a letter associated with it. If it were `1A-24-1981` then yes regex should id it

Comment: if your matches are always `xxx-xxx-xxx` then you could try `\S+-\S+-\S+`

Comment: @Datanovice the matches could be any combination of `xx-x-x` or `x-xxx-xx` or `xxx-x-xxx` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex might do the trick.

`(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(\S+-\S+-\S+)`

It matches everything between two spaces that has two `-` in it. Also there won't be a match if there is no letter present.

[regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/M4bAe4/1)

As you can see for the given input you provided only `1-A16-19`, `BL-17-1111`, `Z-1-12` & `1A-256-29Q88` are getting returned.

Comment: what would the full line of code look like? e.g. `x = re.search(\S*-\S*-\S*, dataframe)` `

Comment: and the code above would inadvertently pick up `12-24-1981`

Answer (score 0):

you could try :

```
vals = df['Date'].str.extractall(r'(\S+-\S+-\S+)')[0].tolist() 
# extract your strings based on your condition above and pass to a list.
# make a list with the index range of your matches.
nums = []
for x,y in enumerate(vals):
    nums.append(x)
```

## pass both lists into a dictionary.

```
my_dict = dict(zip(nums,vals))
print(my_dict)
 {0: '1-A16-19',
 1: 'BL-17-1111',
 2: 'Z-1-12',
 3: '12-24-1981',
 4: '1A-256-29Q88'}
```

if you want the index to start at one you can specify this in the `enumerate` function.

```
for x,y in enumerate(vals,1):
    nums.append(x)
print(nums)
[1, 2, 3,4,5]
```

Comment: I get an `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tolist'` when I enter  `vals = df['Date'].str.extract(r'(\S+-\S+-\S+)')[0].tolist()`

Comment: what do you get when you print the line without `.tolist()`

Comment: i get `'1-A16-19'`

Comment: updated my answer - above should work, it works for me anyway.

Comment: Using `vals = dataframe['Date'].str.extract(r'(\S+-\S+-\S+)')` works!

Comment: change `extract` to `extractall` to find all the matches.

Comment: actually this code is really close but picks up `12-24-1981` which it shouldn't